# Не получается динамически изменить параметр loop. И почему не работает .swiper-button-prev?

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h59nkjoy/5/

```js
let album_images_slider = new Swiper("#album_images_slider", {
  direction: "horizontal",
  allowTouchMove: false,
  speed: 600,
  // autoplay: {
  //     delay: 3000
  // },

  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev"
  }
});

let albums_slider = new Swiper("#albums_slider", {
  direction: "horizontal",
  spaceBetween: 30,
  slidesPerView: 4,
  allowTouchMove: false,
  speed: 600,
  // autoplay: {
  //     delay: 3000
  // },

  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev"
  }
});
$(function() {
  if (album_images_slider.slides.length < 2) {
    album_images_slider.params.loop = false;
    album_images_slider.update();
    console.log(album_images_slider.params.loop);
  } else {
    album_images_slider.params.loop = true;
    album_images_slider.update();
    console.log(album_images_slider.params.loop);
  }


})
```

```css
.layer {
  display: -webkit-box!important;
  display: -ms-flexbox!important;
  display: flex!important;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: rgb(36, 36, 36);
  color: #fff;
}

#album_images_slider_scale {
  width: 1200px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#album_images_slider_scale .swiper-slide {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: rgb(55, 55, 55);
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
}

#album_images_slider_scale img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0!important;
  border: none!important;
}

#album_images_slider {
  width: 600px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#album_images_slider .swiper-slide {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: rgb(55, 55, 55);
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
}

#album_images_slider img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Berkshire+Swash" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/album.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/swiper_init.js"></script>
<script src="js/album.js" defer></script>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="swiper-container" id="album_images_slider">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DtQ5AhzX4AUGQeL.jpg:large">
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://dbw4iivs1kce3.cloudfront.net/680x/2013/06/media-image-346120-article-ajust_930.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://stihi.ru/pics/2019/11/13/5598.jpg">
    </div>


  </div>
  <div class="swiper-navigation">
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

У меня есть слайдер с изображениями (`album_images_slider`). В одном из своих предыдущих вопросов на русском SO, мне ответили, что для того, чтобы в слайдере не дублировались изображения, когда их меньше, чем значение параметра slidesPerView или когда их количество равно slidesPerView, нужно прописать `loop: false`.

Поэтому я решил исключить инициализацию параметра `loop` в слайдере (удалил строку `loop: true`) из объявления слайдера, и задавать `loop: false`, если количество слайдов меньше либо равно slidesPerView, а в противном случае задавать `loop: true`.

Значение loop изменяется, console.log() показывает, что всё в порядке, но при этом почему-то само по себе изменение loop не даёт никакого эффекта.

Из-за того, что `loop: true` было удалено из объявления слайдера, теперь в слайдере при любом количестве находящихся в нем слайдов отсутствует поведение `loop`. К тому же почему-то не работает `.swiper-button-prev`, кнопка почему-то всегда имеет класс disabled.

**Как сделать так, чтобы `loop` изменялся динамически? И как сделать так, чтобы заработал .swiper-button-prev?**

**UPD: Я попробовал удалять и заново создавать Swiper:**

```
$(function() {
    if (album_images_slider.slides.length < 2) {
        album_images_slider.params.loop = false;
        album_images_slider.update();
        console.log(album_images_slider.params.loop);
    }
    else {
        delete album_images_slider;
        let album_images_slider = new Swiper("#album_images_slider", {
            direction: "horizontal",
            allowTouchMove: false,
            speed: 600,
            loop: true,

            navigation: {
                nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
                prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev"
            }
        });
        console.log(album_images_slider.params.loop);
    }

})
```

Теперь по какой-то причине заработал .swiper-button-prev, но `loop` всё не работает, хотя console.log показывает, что `loop: true`

Comment: Код надо добавлять в вопрос.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko добавил

Comment: Хорошо бы и html добавить. Цель в том, что бы ваш вопрос остался полезен и другим людям в будущем. Для этого непосредственно в вопросе нужен код, который воспроизводит проблему. Ссылки на сторонние ресурсы(фидл) не подходят, потому что вы его можете удалить\изменить\пофиксить и тогда вопрос потеряет ценность.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko добавил

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko добавил в вопрос еще информации о проблеме

Comment: У вас ошибки в консоли на фидле :(

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko исправил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может, вам подойдет такое решение.  Если количество слайдов больше 2, то включаем `loop` при инициализации слайдера.

```js
const countSlides = $("#album_images_slider .swiper-slide").length;

let album_images_slider = new Swiper("#album_images_slider", {
  direction: "horizontal",
  allowTouchMove: false,
  loop: countSlides > 2, // если количество слайдов больше 2, то включаем loop 
  speed: 600,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev"
  }
});
```

```css
.layer {
  display: -webkit-box!important;
  display: -ms-flexbox!important;
  display: flex!important;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: rgb(36, 36, 36);
  color: #fff;
}

#album_images_slider_scale {
  width: 1200px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#album_images_slider_scale .swiper-slide {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: rgb(55, 55, 55);
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
}

#album_images_slider_scale img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0!important;
  border: none!important;
}

#album_images_slider {
  width: 600px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#album_images_slider .swiper-slide {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: rgb(55, 55, 55);
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
}

#album_images_slider img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Berkshire+Swash" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/album.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/swiper_init.js"></script>
<script src="js/album.js" defer></script>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="swiper-container" id="album_images_slider">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DtQ5AhzX4AUGQeL.jpg:large">
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://dbw4iivs1kce3.cloudfront.net/680x/2013/06/media-image-346120-article-ajust_930.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://stihi.ru/pics/2019/11/13/5598.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-navigation">
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="enableLoop">Enable loop</button>
<button id="disableLoop">Disable loop</button>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: Можете пожалуйста помочь с этой проблемой? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1241643/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%88%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%81